# Export contacts, groups, and distribution lists from Microsoft Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, export, distribution-list

I want to get an overview of people and distribution lists/groups for my organization's exchange installation. I want to do it regularly and there are too many users and groups to do it manually. So I aim for an (semi-)automated approach.

I have a Microsoft Outlook 2016 at hand and also the Outlook Web Access (or whatever its current name is).

There are many google hits for exporting the Global Address List to CSV which works fine (and is semi-automatic), but unfortunately, distribution lists/groups are empty.

Is there any way I can export them, too? Somehow? (I'm desperate. It does not need to be automated.)

Answer (score 0):

To get the distribution group and all the group members' list, try this script:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-all-distribution-707c27eb

Comment: Wow, that looks like a good starting point but it seems to me that this relies on something called _Exchange Management Shell_ which is available only on the system running the Exchange Server. I have just the client installation and cannot call these functions required there. :-(

Comment: Hi Tobias，you can install Exchange Management Shell on client computer:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232090(v=exchg.160).aspx.  By clicking the other versions, you can check the document for Exchange 2007/2010/2013.